# OpenCV, Android: color detection from particular area or portion of an image?

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap

I want to detect the entire area below the black object.

I've managed to get the rectangle area below the black object like so

```
    Point leftPoint = new Point(0,yValueBlack); //far left, black object height
    Point rightPoint = new Point(sourceBitmap.getWidth(),sourceBitmap.getHeight()); //btm right of entire bitmap

    Rect bottomRect = new Rect(leftPoint,rightPoint);
```

Whereby `Rect bottomRect = new Rect(leftPoint,rightPoint);`  is the area i want to detect the green strip in, like in the picture. This is to prevent the application from searching anything above the picture and causing error when other objects are in frame.

I have a bitmap of the black object bounded by a bounding rectangle, I want to detect only `Rect bottomRect = new Rect(leftPoint,rightPoint);`  from that bitmap & then draw the bounding rectangle for the green strip.

The way i defined my mat's size is like this
`Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);`

However when i tried to use the same method to define my mat size to fit the rectangle area below black object like so:
`Mat croppedMat = new Mat(bottomRect, CvType.CV_8UC3);`
It'd give me an error.

Here's how it would look like I think:

> 1. Detect and draw bounding rectangle around black object (Done)
> 2. Find rectangle area(RAT) below black object
> 3. Detect and draw bounding rectangle around green object within the RAT(I can detect and draw bounding rectangle for green object, cant seem to do it WITHIN the specified RAT)
> 4. Display bitmap like shown in image below(done)

[image]

**EDIT:**

after detecting the black object, the bounding rect is drawn and is currently on `roiBitmap`. Cropping the `roiBitmap` and trying to display it(I'd be detecting the green tape from this bitmap that's cropped out eventually.) in an `imageview` is giving me error:

> CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:483: error: (-215) 0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows in function cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Range&, const cv::Range&)

my code:

```
private Bitmap findCombine(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
        Bitmap roiBitmap = null;
        Scalar green = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
        Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);
        Mat roiTmp = sourceMat.clone();
        bitmapWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
        Log.e("bitmapWidth", String.valueOf(bitmapWidth));
        final Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
        sourceMat.copyTo(hsvMat);

        // convert mat to HSV format for Core.inRange()
        Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        Scalar lowerb = new Scalar(85, 50, 40);         // lower color border for BLUE
        Scalar upperb = new Scalar(135, 255, 255);      // upper color border for BLUE

        Scalar lowerblack = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);         // lower color border for BLACK
        Scalar upperblack = new Scalar(180, 255, 40);      // upper color border for BLACK

        Scalar testRunL = new Scalar(60, 50, 40); // lower Green   83 100 51
        Scalar testRunU = new Scalar(90, 255, 255); // upper Green

        Core.inRange(hsvMat, lowerblack, upperblack, roiTmp);   // select only blue pixels
        // find contours
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        List<RotatedRect> boundingRects = new ArrayList<>();
        Imgproc.findContours(roiTmp, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // find appropriate bounding rectangles
        for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
            MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
            RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);

            double rectangleArea = boundingRect.size.area();

            // test min ROI area in pixels
            if (rectangleArea > 1300 && rectangleArea < 500000) {//400000
                Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
                boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);
                Rect rect3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));

                Log.e("blackArea", String.valueOf(rect3.area()));
                // test horizontal ROI orientation
                if (rect3.height > rect3.width) {
                    Imgproc.rectangle(sourceMat, rect3.tl(), rect3.br(), green, 3);
                    xBlack = rect3.br().x;
                    yBlack = rect3.br().y;//bottom
                    battHeight = (rect3.br().y - rect3.tl().y); //batt height in pixel
                    Log.e("BLACKBR, TL", String.valueOf(rect3.br().y) + "," + String.valueOf(rect3.tl().y));
                }

            }

        }
  

   roiBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat.cols(), sourceMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(sourceMat, roiBitmap);


    Point leftPoint = new Point(0, yBlack); //far left, black object height
    Point rightPoint = new Point(roiBitmap.getWidth(), roiBitmap.getHeight()); //btm right of entire bitmap

    Rect bottomRect = new Rect(leftPoint, rightPoint);
    double rectWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 0;
    double rectHeight = sourceBitmap.getHeight() - yBlack;
    Log.e("rectWidth", String.valueOf(rectWidth));
    Log.e("rectHeight", String.valueOf(rectHeight));
    Size bottomRectSize = new Size(rectHeight, rectWidth);

    Bitmap cropBitmap = null;
    Bitmap sourceBitmapT = null;

    Mat sourceMatT = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Log.e("sourceMatT, BottomRect","SMT "+ String.valueOf(sourceMatT.size()) + " bottomRect " + String.valueOf(bottomRect.size()));


    Mat cropMat = new Mat(sourceMatT, bottomRect);
    ImageView imgCropped = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropped_image_view);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(roiBitmap, sourceMatT);
    //mgCropped.setImageBitmap(sourceBitmapT);

    Utils.matToBitmap(cropMat, cropBitmap);
    imgCropped.setImageBitmap(cropBitmap);
```

`Log.e("sourceMatT, BottomRect","SMT "+ String.valueOf(sourceMatT.size()) + " bottomRect " + String.valueOf(bottomRect.size()));`

returned me these values:

> sourceMatT, BottomRect: SMT 1920x1080 bottomRect 1080x656

Comment: `Mat croppedMat = new Mat(bottomRect, CvType.CV_8UC3);` gives an error because there is no such thing as this _Mat_ constructor. I guess what you are looking for is this one: `Mat(Mat m, Rect roi) `. Next time, please look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/) first.

Comment: Hey @ElouarnLaine I've edited the question to reflect my current issue :x I'd appreciate some help if you are able to figure out what's wrong Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "extract" part of image, then find contours in entire extracted area, then correct coords of find contours. Something like that:

Extract part of `sourceMat`:

```
// set top left position and dimensions of extracted area
int topLeftX = ...;
int topLeftY = ...;
int width = ...;
int height = ...;

// create Rect object for extracted area
Rect extractedRect = new Rect (topLeftX, topLeftY, width, height);

// create Mat from sourceMat
Mat extractedMat = new Mat(sourceMat, extractedRect);
```

Find contours/rectangles or something else on entire extracted area:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(extractedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Correct coords of founded contours (add to it's `X` and `Y` coords, corresponding, `topLeftX` and `topLeftY` for right placing on `sourceMat`):

```
List<Rect> rectsOnSourcemat = new ArrayList<>();

for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
    MatOfPoint2f contourPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
    RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);
    Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
    boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);

    // correct coords here for sourceMat:
    for (int ixPoint = 0; ixPoint < 4; ixPoint++) {
        rotated_rect_points[ixPoint].x += topLeftX;  
        rotated_rect_points[ixPoint].y += topLeftY;  
    }

    // crate bounding rect for sourceMat
    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));
    rectsOnSourcemat.add(rect);
}
```

Now in `rectsOnSourcemat` variable You'll got list of rects of founded on extracted area objects, but already with coords for `sourceMat`.